# How debug ejb module in netbeans 7.3

Tags: ejb

How debug ejb module in Netbeans. I have created Enterprise Application. Then I made client of enterprise application. This client uses ejb module with @Remote interface. How can I debug it Netbeans?
When I start debug client app starts but breakpoints dont work in code of EJB module?